# How to remove currency symbol from XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to remove currency euro symbol from xml code? Below I paste output date xml.

XML input:

```
<products>
<product>
<sku>BTKUJ-1-2-2-3</sku>
<price>20€</price>
</product>
</products>
```

Sample XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="products">
<xsl:element name="products">
  <xsl:for-each select="product">
    <xsl:element name="product">
                    <xsl:element name="sku">
                        AVM0TCPD_<xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="priceimp">
                        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                    </xsl:element>-->
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected result:

```
<products>
<product>
<sku>BTKUJ-1-2-2-3</sku>
**<price>20</price>**
</product>
</products>
```

Comment: Why does your code use `<xsl:element name="priceimp">` if the expected result is supposed to have a `price` element? Use `translate` with e.g. `translate(., '€', '')` to remove the symbol from the value.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find the logic in your attempt. If all you want to do is remove the euro symbol from the `price` element, you should do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '€', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```